# Using pandas groupby on two column how to derived a new column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have Dataset which has many columns and I want create a new column based on two columns on that dataset.

```
   train_data[['CtpJobId', 'SegmentId']]

     CtpJobId     SegmentId
0   qa1-9epx-dk1    347772
1   qa1-9epx-dv1    347774
2   qa1-9epx-dv1    347777
3   qa1-9epx-dv1    347780
4   qa1-9epx-dv1    347783
5   qa1-9epx-dv1    347786
6   qa1-9epx-dv1    347789
7   qa1-9epx-dv1    347792
8   qa1-9epx-e01    347794
9   qa1-9epx-eb2    347795
10  qa1-9epx-ez1    347796
11  qa1-9epx-f32    347797
12  qa1-9epx-fi1    347798
```

Now I want create a new column called numberOfSegment such as if same jobId has multiple segmentId then aggregate that segmentId and insert that sum up to that new column.

```
      CtpJobId        SegmentId    numberOfSegment
0   qa1-9epx-dk1    347772             1
1   qa1-9epx-dv1    347774             7
2   qa1-9epx-dv1    347777             7
3   qa1-9epx-dv1    347780             7
4   qa1-9epx-dv1    347783             7
5   qa1-9epx-dv1    347786             7
6   qa1-9epx-dv1    347789             7
7   qa1-9epx-dv1    347792             7
8   qa1-9epx-e01    347794             1
9   qa1-9epx-eb2    347795             1
10  qa1-9epx-ez1    347796             1
11  qa1-9epx-f32    347797             1
```

I did in one way but it gives wrong

```
train_data['NumberOfSegment'] = train_data.groupby('CtpJobId')['SegmentId'].sum()

 train_data[['CtpJobId','NumberOfSegment']]

   CtpJobId    NumberOfSegment
0   qa1-9epx-dk1    NaN
1   qa1-9epx-dv1    NaN
2   qa1-9epx-dv1    NaN
3   qa1-9epx-dv1    NaN
4   qa1-9epx-dv1    NaN
5   qa1-9epx-dv1    NaN
6   qa1-9epx-dv1    NaN
7   qa1-9epx-dv1    NaN
8   qa1-9epx-e01    NaN
9   qa1-9epx-eb2    NaN
10  qa1-9epx-ez1    NaN
```

Can Anyone please help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with `'count'`.

```
train_data['NumberOfSegment'] = train_data.groupby('CtpJobId')['SegmentId'].transform('count')
```

Output:

```
        CtpJobId  SegmentId  NumberOfSegment
0   qa1-9epx-dk1     347772                1
1   qa1-9epx-dv1     347774                7
2   qa1-9epx-dv1     347777                7
3   qa1-9epx-dv1     347780                7
4   qa1-9epx-dv1     347783                7
5   qa1-9epx-dv1     347786                7
6   qa1-9epx-dv1     347789                7
7   qa1-9epx-dv1     347792                7
8   qa1-9epx-e01     347794                1
9   qa1-9epx-eb2     347795                1
10  qa1-9epx-ez1     347796                1
11  qa1-9epx-f32     347797                1
12  qa1-9epx-fi1     347798                1
```

Answer (score 4):

You may also `map` a `value_counts` result to "CtpJobId":

```
df['NumberOfSegment'] = df.CtpJobId.map(df.CtpJobId.value_counts())    
df

        CtpJobId  SegmentId  NumberOfSegment
0   qa1-9epx-dk1     347772                1
1   qa1-9epx-dv1     347774                7
2   qa1-9epx-dv1     347777                7
3   qa1-9epx-dv1     347780                7
4   qa1-9epx-dv1     347783                7
5   qa1-9epx-dv1     347786                7
6   qa1-9epx-dv1     347789                7
7   qa1-9epx-dv1     347792                7
8   qa1-9epx-e01     347794                1
9   qa1-9epx-eb2     347795                1
10  qa1-9epx-ez1     347796                1
11  qa1-9epx-f32     347797                1
12  qa1-9epx-fi1     347798                1
```

Comment: This one is the best answer listed down +1

Comment: @MHossain I understand, no worries

Answer (score 3):

You need to **`groupby`** and **`transform`**

```
df.groupby('CtpJobId').SegmentId.transform('count')

0     1
1     7
2     7
3     7
4     7
5     7
6     7
7     7
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    1
Name: SegmentId, dtype: int64
```